# Como imprimir cores de fundo em HTML com CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
<div id="div0">
    I love ...
</div>
<div id="div1">
Teste
</div>

<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Coluna 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 3
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 4
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 5
        </td>

    </tr>
            <td>
            Coluna 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 3
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 4
        </td>
        <td>
            Coluna 5
        </td>

    </tr>
```

```
 #div0 {
    background-color:#FF0000; 
}
#div1{
    background-color: #FFD6D6;
}
#table:
{
    background-color: #170E0E;
}
```

Quero que saia exatamente igual essas div.

Quando mando imprimir sai apenas o texto, e a tabela sem as cores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Chrome e Safari (e possivelmente em outros browsers baseados em Webkit), existe a propriedade não-padrão [`-webkit-print-color-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-print-color-adjust), que pode ser definida como `exact` para forçar a impressão das cores de fundo:

```
body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Isso força a impressão para todos os descendentes do body (mas o body em si é uma exceção, e sua cor de fundo não é impressa).

Em outros browsers é possível forçar a impressão dos fundos alterando uma configuração, geralmente disponível no próprio diálogo de impressão.

Comment: Funcionou!... obrigado

Comment: Só não se esqueça que só funciona em alguns browsers!

Comment: no firefox e ie como fica? pode fazer algo generico?

Comment: Acho que não tem como. Só alterando as configs do browser na hora de imprimir.