# Quais fontes eu posso garantir que estarão disponíveis em todas as plataformas?

Tags: html

Quais as fontes eu poderia garantir que estivesse disponível seja qual for a plataforma.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Utilização de tag de renderização de HTML em Jboss Seam Pdf](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/467839/utiliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-tag-de-renderiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-html-em-jboss-seam-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

[Este link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) mostra fontes seguras para se usar em todos os navegadores/plataformas.
Porém sempre atribua mais de uma fonte em `font-family` no css, colocando primeiramente a fonte desejada e em seguida fontes parecidas. Assim caso a primeira fonte não esteja disponível, o navegador procurará a segunda, e assim por diante.